# How can this error- Duplicate class error Dagger Hilt be solved?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, clean-architecture, dagger-hilt

I have different modules in my app following the clean architecture , some are pure kotlin modules and other android modules, but when I try to compile the app, I get the duplicate class error.

````
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class dagger.hilt.codegen.OriginatingElement found in modules jetified-hilt-android-2.28.3-alpha-runtime (com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28.3-alpha) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.hilt.processor.internal.aggregateddeps.AggregatedDeps found in modules jetified-hilt-android-2.28.3-alpha-runtime (com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28.3-alpha) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.AnnotationMirrors found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.AnnotationMirrors$1 found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.AnnotationMirrors$2 found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.AnnotationValues found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.AnnotationValues$1 found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.AnnotationValues$1$1 found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.AnnotationValues$1$1$1 found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.AnnotationValues$1$1$2 found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.AnnotationValues$1$1$3 found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.AnnotationValues$1$1$4 found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.AnnotationValues$1$2 found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor$1 found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor$2 found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)
     Duplicate class dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor$ElementName found in the following modules: jetified-dagger-compiler-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28.3), jetified-dagger-spi-2.28.3 (com.google.dagger:dagger-spi:2.28.3) and jetified-hilt-android-compiler-2.28.3-alpha (com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28.3-alpha)```
````

Comment: It's unclear without your Gradle files. Looks like you has some duplicated dependencies here

Answer (score 6):

I was using implementation to add the dependency instead of kapt, after I changed that, everything was okay

Comment: So after 4 hours of  figuring out all sorts of solutions this one  works! Thanks man!